# Issue decoding Base64 JSON data

Tags: json, swiftui, base64, picker

Any pointers would be much appreciated.  No build or run errors with the code below, but 239 "Fail" prints in the Console.  Also, once I get it to work properly, this code should be in a separate function or extension and not part of the View, and for reusability.  I am expecting to see a country's flag next to its name in a Picker listing.  The 'country.name' displays and 'selectedCountry' can be selected for subsequent Core Data storage, but sadly no flag displays. The relevant code and a sample "Country" from the JSON file below:

In the Properties section:

```
let countryImage: [Country] = Bundle.main.decode("Countries.json")
@State private var selectedContact: [ContactEntity] = []
let flag = "flag"
```

In the View:

```
VStack {
                Picker(selection: $selectedCountry,
                       label: Text("Host Country:")) {
                    ForEach(countryImage) { country in
                        HStack {
                        Text(country.name).tag(country.name)
                        // TODO - Find Flag
                            if case country.flag = Data(base64Encoded: flag), let uiImage = UIImage(data: country.flag) {
                                Image(uiImage: uiImage).tag(country.flag)
                        } else {
                            let _ = print("Fail")
                        }
                        //Image(flag)
                        }
                    }
                }
                       .padding(.horizontal, 0)
                       .padding()
                       .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            }//: INNER PICKER VSTACK
```

The Bundle references an extension:

```
extension Bundle {
func decode<T: Codable>(_ file: String) -> T { // "_" obviates the need to call the name of the parameter
    // 1. Locate the JSON file
    guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
        fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
    }
    
    // 2. Create a property for the data
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
    }
    
    // 3. Create a decoder
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    // 4. Create a property for the decoded data
    guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
    }
    // 5. Return the ready-to-use data
    return loaded
}
```

}

Sample JSON item:

> {
> "id": 202,
> "name": "Sudan",
> "isoAlpha2": "SD",
> "isoAlpha3": "SDN",
> "isoNumeric": 736,
> "currency": {
> "code": "SDD",
> "name": "Dinar",
> "symbol": false
> },
> "flag": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAUCAYAAACaq43EAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyRpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMy1jMDExIDY2LjE0NTY2MSwgMjAxMi8wMi8wNi0xNDo1NjoyNyAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNiAoTWFjaW50b3NoKSIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDozNjc2Q0MxMjE3ODgxMUUyQTcxNDlDNEFCRkNENzc2NiIgeG1wTU06RG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDozNjc2Q0MxMzE3ODgxMUUyQTcxNDlDNEFCRkNENzc2NiI+IDx4bXBNTTpEZXJpdmVkRnJvbSBzdFJlZjppbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOkY1RTdDNTBCMTc4NzExRTJBNzE0OUM0QUJGQ0Q3NzY2IiBzdFJlZjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOkY1RTdDNTBDMTc4NzExRTJBNzE0OUM0QUJGQ0Q3NzY2Ii8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+dsEThQAAAfVJREFUeNq8lT9oE1Ecxz/v3ZmkMae2xdbuiqRiqaugKDo5WFGQOiiimy5aR6dOOrhYHRx0qQoVaQOCbgpO/oHatTrVhCYNtIlJbWJJ7p6/C7aiVhfv5Qf3jrt33Of9vt/f7z118sTe+TvPE15XQzHbGaABZbAeihu7zc6sw71MB0cWXGY9n28uOJbhDgM910q9QXx8oEFnVXMsu6mVcSVuF64lZ1jUrYcrp2sMD9XwBbinpPFlzihb4LVxRQhlzdP9qxy6sMKbHT6DZYdYk9YCovd4JF2Vu7f+JpS3O4BVuPUiydXpBPMUKLLc+tweOAzhkpIVxJsMv1bm/rZTfrK7y2QrBWUi8t39qwGh9HWHiX1l9bF/znl8/rpJk1LReryxFiK7I0MPMy8nVf+lXfrhh2fqx8x/X/rf6xJdfR/60tAMOHdziMNjZyguL1rM+I+OF1caUKpXpd2MJY9/BxY/QSzJ3ZFxLh84a7G41toq3MJ0haMHj5tHFx+Y3giLa2NwIMDNMpWSje1V0WzJav/2zKjJfVlQgQksgUPo9oT4KYBMHvO+rKaYcKPeuX7+MCwYR2qtrwPmvsJUDgp1a4eE+4u0W2PwVlplMmv9PHbXpZU+5clnmF6iHeGKtB65mkgrWebrtCtc3i3lyeQ8jKGd8V2AAQDj9qv7QrTRKwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
> },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than expected. `Decodable` can decode a base64-encoded String directly as `Data`

In `Country` declare `flag`

```
let flag: Data?
```

and a computed property

```
var flagImage : UIImage? {
    guard let flagData = flag else { return nil }
    return UIImage(data: flagData)
}
```

And display the image

```
if let flagImage = country.flagImage { 
    Image(uiImage: flagImage).tag(country.flag)
} else {
    let _ = print("Fail")
}
```

Comment: It works!  I am grateful for your rapid response.

Comment: Hi Vadian, I put the code to display the flagImage inside the Picker and it works fine - long list of country names with their flags, but I have spent a few hours trying to get the flag to display outside the picker as well, but I cannot find/create the property to link back to the chosen country to reference the flag.  Any ideas?

Comment: `countryImage` is on the top level. You can access it everywhere inside the struct. By the way a more meaningful name is `countries`.

Comment: I have changed to 'countries' - makes sense.  The issue persists- how to reference the 'selectedCountry''s flag.  All the variables in the Picker fall out of scope outside the Picker.  JSON apparently has no referencing capability and I am at loss as to how to create the link from 'selectedCountry' to say 'selectedFlag' to use in an Image outside the Picker.  Hopefully the answer is not to put the JSON contents into SQLite3/CoreData!

Comment: It's not enough information in the question. Please ask a new one and provide more information for example how the code snippets are related to each other and to the context.