# base64encoded image not showing up in UIImageView

Tags: swift, base64, uiimage

So I have some avatars that are stored in my database as base64encoded strings, something like...

`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJC...`

From everything I have read online I should be able to load those into UIImages just fine by using the data. I have tried so many things, and nothing can make the image show up. Most of them the data was nil after converting it, the closest I got, which makes the data not nil is this...

```
let avatarData = Data(base64Encoded: avatarString!, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
cell.userAvatar.image = UIImage(data: avatarData!)
```

If I print the avatarData I get

> Optional(39990 bytes)

So There is definitely something there, but image on screen is not there, it's just completely blank. I even tried starting a new project, manually making the avatarString a let in the class and manually adding the image to the screen...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let avatarString = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2w..."
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (view.frame.midX - 110), y: (view.frame.midY - 110), width: 120, height: 120))
    let avatarData = Data(base64Encoded: avatarString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: avatarData!)
    view.addSubView(imageView)
  }
}
```

When the app loads up on an emulator the screen is completely blank. No image, nothing. To test I manually added another image, something from the assets and it loads up just fine (I did it programmatically, the same way I'm trying to add the avatar image). No matter what I do the image won't show up on the screen. If I remove the `options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters` part of the Data call then the avatarData is nil.

The images were uploaded from a react app and turned into the data string, then saved in the database. They are retrieved from an API call and are returned as strings. All of the stuff I have found online, and on here have said, just use the `Data(base64Encoded` call and it will work, but the images just do not show up. I know they are good because they show up on a webpage with the same data string from the database, I just can't get them to show up in iOS at all.

Thank you so much, and I apologize for the horrible formatting. I've been pulling my hair out all day trying to figure out why the images won't show up and I'm at my last wit. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that `"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2w..."` is not a valid base 64 encoded string. Please provide the _actual_ string that you have. Otherwise there is no way for us to try this and see for ourselves. (For example, you could post it on GitHub as a Gist.)

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620010/issue-decoding-base64-json-data 
you will find a base64 string, ("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg ..."). Use this in your `let avatarString = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg ..."`  to see if an image shows up with your code.

Comment: @matt that is the actual string. I get it from the database. It's created on the web, in a react app that uses `const reader = new FileReader(); reader.onload = (event) => { resolve(event.target.result); }; reader.readAsDataURL(file);` so I guess technically it's a data url.

Comment: A base 64 string wouldn't have three dots at the end like your `...` So what you are showing us is not the actual string. So we have no way to test what your code is actually doing. If you want help, you must show us the _actual_ string.

Comment: @matt it is insanely long, but I will post it up in my original question. Sorry I misunderstood you. Editing this comment. I am unable to provide the full string. When I do I get an error saying body length is too long. The string is over 30k characters

Comment: That is why I suggest you make it a GitHub gist. Did you actually _read_ my comment?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this approach, where you "extract" the base64encoded part from the string you get from the API/database.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let avatarString = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/b64string....."
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (view.frame.midX - 110), y: (view.frame.midY - 110), width: 120, height: 120))
        
        // or some other scheme to remove the first non-b64string part of the string
        let b64string = avatarString.replacingOccurrences(of: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/", with: "")
        
        if let avatarData = Data(base64Encoded: b64string),
           let img = UIImage(data: avatarData) {
            imageView.image = img
            view.addSubView(imageView)
        } else {
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you may need to keep the `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/` as part of the base64 string data. In that case use:

```
 let b64string = avatarString.replacingOccurrences(of: "data:image/jpeg;base64,", with: "")
```